# Sql get data from two tables with a twist

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, join

I want two get data from two dables
users and data listed below

```
User table -->

id name   time
 1 first  2016-04-20 15:13:13
 2 second 2016-04-20 15:13:13
 3 third  2016-04-20 15:13:13
 4 forth  2016-04-20 15:13:13
 5 fifth  2016-04-20 15:13:13

Data table -->

id data user_id time
 1 2000       1 2016-04-20 15:10:18
 2 3000       2 2016-04-20 15:10:18
 3 4000       3 2016-04-20 15:10:18
 4 2000       4 2016-04-20 15:10:18
 5 3000       5 2016-04-20 15:10:18
```

can join them easily by

```
select d.data
     , u.name 
  from data d
  left 
  join users u 
    on d.user_id = u.id 
 order 
    by d.data DESC
```

its gives -->

```
data name
4000 third
3000 fifth
3000 second
2000 forth 
2000 first
```

But i want it like only with sql query (can be done with a muti dim array)

any way i want only with query

```
data name name
2000 first forth
3000 second fifth
4000 third
```

Plz guide me

Comment: you can get output with comma separated like first,forth using concat_ws()

Comment: You mention PHP, so just use a php loop to spit the data out in the desired arrangement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` to group the results by the field you want and then `GROUP_CONCAT` function, an aggregate function, to concatenate the strings from each group into a single string.

```
 select data.data,GROUP_CONCAT(users.name) from data left join users on   
 data.user_id=users.id GROUP BY data.data order by data.data DESC
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.data,GROUP_CONCAT(u.name) from data d left join users u on   
 d.user_id=u.id GROUP BY d.data order by d.data DESC
```

'Group_concat'  returns all the corresponding values of column name from users